# WAR file deployed on Tomcat not reading application.properties File

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat8

I've created a Demo REST API using Spring Boot Framework in Java. I wanted to deploy this API on Tomcat 8 as a WAR file. The API is already configured to compile down as a WAR file using Spring Initializr. But, when the API is deployed, its not reading `application.properties` file from the project.

- I've already tried using `@PropertySource` and `@PropertySources` annotations.
- I've also tried including `<resources>` tag in `<build>` tag in pom.xml file.
- I've also tried adding `.properties("classpath:application.properties")` to `ServletInitializer`

Nothing worked

## Update

I've used context-path as an example in this post. In my actual application, I have some properties stored in application.properties and the application is not reading them.

**Here's my code files:**

- application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

- Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

- ServletInitializer.java

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

- User.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class User {

    @GetMapping("")
    public String getUser() {
        return "User is here...";
    }
}
```

Hitting `localhost:8080/demo/api/user` URL should give our desired output, but its rather giving a 404 result. Whereas, hitting `localhost:8080/demo/user` is giving the desired output.
This means that the applicaiton is not reading application.properties file because the default route of the api was set to `/api` in that file.

Comment: This property can only be honored if Spring Boot starts an embedded web server. If you deploy  a war file into an external app server, then the app can't change its own context path programmatically: the app must already be deployed and started to read the properties file, and if it's deployed and started, then it already has a context path. You have to follow the rules of Tomcat to choose the context path.

Comment: I created this Demo application just to post this question. In my actual application, I have some properties to read from properties file and they are not being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only embedded tomcat honors the `server.servlet.context-path`. If you are deploying to an external tomcat, follow the guidelines here to set the context path: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html

Now, verify whether `application.properties` is bundled in the `WAR` file. To do this extract or open the `WAR` file. If not included then verify your build file whether resource plugin is copying the resource files.

If the `application.properties` is included in the WAR then, try reading other properties in your application.